# ShowInTaskBar bug when ChildWindow has a ChildWindow with ShowInTaskBar = false and all taskbar of disappear

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Window WindowA that will open ChildWindowB with ChildWindowB.Owner = WindowA.
In ChildWindowB i want to open a ChildWindowC with ChildWindowC.Owner = ChildWindowB and ChildWindowC.ShownInTaskBar = false.

Problem is when i open ChildWindowC, the taskbar of WindowA and ChildWindowB will disappear but if ChildWindowC closed, the taskbar appear.

Is it a bug of WPF or i did something wrong?

(please see on this screencast http://screencast.com/t/a7rMTOOpMzvN - uploaded new screencast)

I uploaded my project on https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=c6d447771583bdab&resid=C6D447771583BDAB!104&id=C6D447771583BDAB!104

Comment: You are going to have to add the code because I just did this and it works fine for me

Comment: @JustiPihony: ah you just show a childwindow with :
ChildWindowB childB = new ChildWindowB();
childB.Owner = this;// WindowA
childB.ShowInTaskBar = false;
childB.Show();

and you can see taskbar of Window disappeared.

Comment: That is exactly what I did, this is my button click handler inside the main window: `Window b = new Window();
            b.Title = "Window B";
            b.ShowInTaskbar = true;
            b.Owner = this;
            var button = new Button();
            button.Click += (sender1, e1) =>
            {
                Window c = new Window();
                c.Title = "Window C";
                c.Owner = b;
                c.ShowInTaskbar = false;
                c.Show(); 
            };
            b.Content = button;
            b.Show();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I watched your screencast. It doesn't look like a bug to me. It looks like Windows is making a judgment call about what to show in the alt+tab menu based on the topmost form you have open.

- When you only had WindowA open with ShowInTaskbar = true, it showed MainWindow in the alt+tab menu.
- When you opened WindowB, which also had ShowInTaskbar = true, it showed the title of that form (ChildWindowB) in the menu instead.
- Once you opened WindowC, with ShowInTaskbar = false, Windows made a judgment to use its settings, so it hid your app from the alt+tab menu.

I don't have a reference to prove this is what's happening... just my observation.

I'm not sure why you'd decide to hide the last window when the other two are visible. Are all your forms showing up separately in the taskbar? I can't see it in that screencast.

Comment: Thanks, nice explain. The last window is a custom messagebox and i don't want it show on taskbar.

Comment: So i can't set both Owner = parentWindow and ShowInTaskbar = false same time in my case. It's weird :(